# Return a pointer to a 2-D array from a C-function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424801/declaring-a-function-returning-a-2-d-array-in-c), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505486/returning-a-2d-array-or-a-pointer-to-one) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794825/how-to-return-a-two-dimensional-pointer-in-c) and many more times, but something's not working yet. I am trying to make a karnaugh map solver in C and I want one of my functions to pass a 2D array back to the main function, so here is my program:

```
    typedef char (*arr)[][4];

    int rows;

    int main(void){
      int noVar;
      char *grid;
      printf("Please Enter the number of variables: ");


      scanf("%d",&noVar);
      grid = setMap(noVar);
      feedOnes(grid);
    }

    arr setMap(int noVar){

    rows = pow(2,noVar)/4;
    char grid[rows][4];
    for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
            grid[i][j]='0';
        }
    }
    printGrid(grid);
    return &grid;
}
```

This gives me an 4 warnings while it does the job for now:

```
    In file included from kmap.c:9:
./setMap.h:33:13: warning: address of stack memory associated with local
      variable 'grid' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return &grid;
            ^~~~
./setMap.h:56:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
      [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
kmap.c:16:8: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'char *' from
      'arr' (aka 'char (*)[][4]') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  grid = setMap(noVar);
       ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
kmap.c:17:12: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *' to parameter
      of type 'char (*)[4]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  feedOnes(grid);
           ^~~~
./setMap.h:36:19: note: passing argument to parameter 'grid' here
int feedOnes(char grid[][4]){
                  ^
```

My question is, can I resolve these warnings? and will these warnings cause any problem in future as I do not know why are they appearing

Also, I am a newbie so please don't be harsh at me if this question was not asked properly..

Thank You.

Comment: and yes, feedOnes is just a program that prints the output.. nothing else

Comment: Did you read the possible duplicates? You cannot return a pointer to an array. Usually, you create the array where you want and pass it to functions as a pointer, do anything you want with the array in the scope you created it, including functions called in the same scope. But returning it is a problem, because it's allocated in a way that will cause deallocation  when it goes out of scope.

Comment: You could try actually doing the things suggested in your links "here, here and here"

Comment: I did try them, but they all generated a bunch of errors, or segmentation faults if grid sizes increased beyond 128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array`grid[][]` is local to the `setMap()` function.  Once this function returns, the variable is no longer available and is out-of-scope.  **Local variables** are declared on the **stack memory**.

In order for something like this to work you will need to **allocate** and **deallocate** memory from the **heap** using the `malloc()` and `free()`function calls respectively.

Refer to this link for clarification on **Stack vs Heap** Memory:

[What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Refer to this link for **scoping in C**:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

Happy Programming!